# Fullpage.js and carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel, fullpage.js

Why two carousels aren't being placed side by side while using fullpage.js ? Without full page.js ,it is working fine!

In Fullpage.js despite dividing the columns into two , the two carousels end up getting overlapped but without it, they're working fine.

Comment: Remove fullpage.js? Job done

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Without one, it's impossible to test any potential fix, which makes your question unanswerable, therefore *off-topic*.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the option `verticalCentered:false`.

fullPage.js uses `display:table` and `display:table-cell` when using such option and that might interfere with your flexbox design (or others).